# Can WiFi absorbing wallpaper absorb enough signal to provide a legitimate security benefit?

Tags: wifi

This [French website](http://www.linformaticien.com/actualites/id/24723/un-papier-peint-pour-proteger-son-wi-fi.aspx) reports that a wifi-absorbing wallpaper provides a security benefit.  Is there any legitimate support for this, assuming that most rooms have windows, and signal can escape from there?

Comment: It helps reduce interference and RF signals seepage outside your required area/zone.

Comment: Keep in mind that this "*absorption*" is far from complete. It merely **helps** absorb RF the same way my curtains "*absorb*" that Saturday morning daylight...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If wallpaper absorbs RF energy and not reflects, then the only way to gain access to wifi is by a direct line of sight through the window. And I would never call Wifi absorbing wallpaper a security measure. Its primary purpose is to reduce interference.

Comment: +1. Drop a microcomputer that has a cellular interface nearby or inside the walls and everything was just undone. This attack is also known as the, "Mail an iPhone with custom firmware," attack. High gain antennas also work. The wallpaper produce a defined db loss, but that can be made up for. Much better for interference help and being a good neighbor than for security.

Comment: @JeffFerland is there any documented usage of this technique?  I never thought of it...